# What's wrong in my code???ValueError: math domain error Python -sqrt

Tags: python, math.sqrt

```
import math
a,b,c = map(int,input().split())
x = float((-b + math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a)
y = float((-b - math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a)

if y>x:
    x = x1
    y = x
    x1 = y
    
if (b**2-4*a*c >=1):
    print("Two different roots "+"x1=",int(x)," , "+"x2=",int(y),sep="")
elif (b**2-4*a*c == 0):
    print("Two same roots x=",int(x),sep="")
else:
    print("No real root")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/7760537/code_7760537.py", line 3, in 
    x = float((-b + math.sqrt(b**2-4*a*c))/2*a)
ValueError: math domain error
```

What's wrong in code??  OAO
What is "math domain error" meaning??
Sorry my English is not good....

Comment: What do you think is the value of `sqrt(b**2-4*a*c)` of `b**2-4*a*c` is negative?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `b**2-4*a*c` gives a negativ number which doesn't work in math, you should put a

```
delta = b**2-4*a*c
if delta > 0:
    x = float((-b + math.sqrt(delta))/2*a)
    y = float((-b - math.sqrt(delta))/2*a)
```

Comment: OK!! I'll try it...